# Can I somehow make a method wait for input from an button/actionlistener

Tags: java, swing

Im working on a simple blackjack game using java swing. Frames and all code is set in place, but I have a huge issue with the players turn, the "best" solution I've found so far is I have to use a while loop waiting for the conditions. This makes the game run but with a load of work for the cpu, which my teachers won't appreciate.

So right now this is the game loop, I have simplified the variables to make it easier to understand. I have searched for solutions for 3 days without any results. Do I have to make some kind of overhaul, or is it possible to just wait for requirment of "playerIsDone" and/or "playerBust" to trigger before moving on to the dealer?

The closest thing to what I want is a scanner, it waits until it has input, I basically want similiar conditions for the players turn.

```
public void run() {
    playerBust = false;
    dealerBust = false;
    // action listener for Hit button
    gameGui.hit.addActionListener(e -> {
        addCardToHand();
        repaint();
    });
    // action listener for Stay button
    gameGui.stay.addActionListener(e -> {
        playerIsDone = true;
        disableButtons();

    });
    // action listener for Play again button
    gameGui.rePlay.addActionListener(e -> {
        playAgain = true;
    });
    while (!exitgame) {
        startGame();
        deal();
        repaint();

        playerTurn();// I want to stay here until requirments are met,  
                     // either the player stays or hits until bust

        dealerTurn();// working loop for dealer

        calculateWinner();// decide a winner

        playAgain(); // enables replay button to replay loop
        disableReplay();
        newRound();
    }

}
```

While the player turn for the time being looks like

```
public void playerTurn() {
    gameGui.enableButtons();
    gameGui.repaint();
    playerIsDone = false;
    
    
    while (!playerBust && !playerIsDone) {
        // This while loop also needed a print to work at all for some reason
        if (calculateHand > 21) {
            gameGui.disableButtons();
            playerBust = true;
        }
        // Condition for playerIsDone lies in the action listener in run().
    }
}
```

I hope all of this explains enough of my issue.

Answer (score 0):

> the "best" solution I've found so far is I have to use a while loop waiting for the conditions.

Whatever source you found that gave you this advice for Swing GUI's, *never* use it again. This advice will work for linear console programs, but is disaster for event-driven GUI's.

And Swing is exactly that, an event-driven GUI library, and so the *best* solution is not to use a busy loop such as this but rather to have event listeners whose behavior (code that is called) will depend on the program's state (the values held by key program fields). For example, the key state to follow here will be something like a userTurn field. A button that the user presses to do an action should only work (and only be active) if it is that user's turn. The user should only be allowed to bet based on fields that tell the program that cards have not been dealt, etc...

Comment: That source is me, still a beginner.

Im still trying to wrap my head around how to clarify for the program that it is the users turn until his turn is finished, I have no clue how to go about it.